Required number of boundary conditions for a partial differential equation
Consider an ordinary differential equation of order $N$ for a function $u(x)$, of the form
$\dot{u} = f\left(u, \frac{du}{dx}, \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}, ..., \frac{d^N u}{dx^N} \right)$.
The number of boundary conditions  required to determine the solution is $N$. For example, if the equation is defined in a segment $x \in [0,1]$, one may specify the first $N$ derivatives of $u$ at $x=0$.
Now consider an analogous system of partial differential equation in two dimensions, for the functions $u^1({\bf x}), \cdots, u^M({\bf x})$, where ${\bf x} = (x,y)$, and the equations are defined in $\Omega \subset {\mathbb R}^2$. The equations contain the first $N_1$ derivatives of $u^1$ , the first $N_2$ derivatives of $u^2$, etc, and are of the same form as the ODE above.
Let us say that fixing the value of $u^i$, or of one of its derivatives, on $\partial \Omega$ is one BC.
How many BC are needed to determine the solutions to the system of PDEs? I know that there is a rule that says 'one BC per unknown, per variable, times the maximal degree of derivative at which the unknown appears'. However, it is unclear how this definition would apply in non-simple domains, i.e., when $\Omega$ is a unit square with a hole in the middle. What would be the correct boundary conditions in this case ?
